# Shell return "PuTTYPuTTYPuTTY..."

Tags: linux, laravel, ssh, composer-php, putty

After "composer global update" command I have found problem when using laravel bash commands.

For example after launch "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed --force" (that have worked well) automatically I found this text in the shell: "PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY..."

Answer (score 9):

The [putty FAQ describes this behavior](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-puttyputty). The command that you are running is issuing some non-printing characters, specifically Ctrl-E, which causes Putty to respond with a string that identifies the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

PuTTY is configured by default to type the string `PuTTY` when it encounters a `^E` character.  See the `Answerback to ^E` field in PuTTY's Terminal settings.

Just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> in a session doesn't generally trigger this, but you can trigger the behaviour by making the terminal print a `Ctrl E` character, which is 0x05 (according to https://www.eso.org/~ndelmott/ascii.html).

One way to do that is with:

```
printf "\5"
```

After this, the string `PuTTY` is typed to the terminal, seemingly as if you'd typed it yourself.

(You can backspace over it, or press Enter and get a `PuTTY: command not found` message.)